# Midi device not showing up for MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()

Tags: java, scala, windows-10, device, midi

I am trying to create an application in Java/Scala that would play some basic Midi on my computer speakers. I succeeded in writing the Midi to a file which runs fine in Windows Media Player, so the Midi sequence is correct, I'd say.

When I run

```
MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo.foreach(println(_))
```

It shows nothing, the result of `MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()` is empty. (Parentheses of getMidiDeviceInfo are intentionally omitted since Scala allows that)

So my question is, how can I create a MidiDevice that connects to my speaker without actually connecting it via Midi?

I have installed VirtualMIDISynth 1.15.2 which made my Midi sound nicer when running it via Windows Media Player, but apparantly it doesn't show up as MidiDevice.

Any help is welcome!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there are no Midi devices. Can you try this: `Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
  for (Info info : infos)` and print `getName()` or something?

Comment: Okay, I've put this code in a Java main method, and it worked... Got 7 devices. After searching somewhat more, it had to do with sbt. Got it fixed by using the fork feature of sbt as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676712/java-sound-devices-found-when-run-in-intellij-but-not-in-sbt

Thanks for the lead. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly it has to do with SBT doing funky things with the classloader. 
Luckily someone else also had this problem and posted the question on SO.

[Java Sound: devices found when run in IntelliJ, but not in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676712/java-sound-devices-found-when-run-in-intellij-but-not-in-sbt)